# view java source code

Tags: java

Is any way to view the actual code behind the default classes in Java (`java.awt.*;`, `javax.swing.*;`, etc) to see *exactly* what it is that is happening?

I don't mean just the documentation, or a list of methods, etc, but the source code itself in full detail (in other words, what could be used to create an exact copy of an entire method/class if copied and pasted into the code for a program in Java).

Comment: In an IDE such as IntelliJ you can browse the source of these packages just like anything else.

Comment: Extending @ChrisMartin, right click the keyword (e.g. `String`) in the editor -> "Go to" -> "Implementation(s)" ... as of idea 14.0.2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Java source code for all the API classes is shipped in the JDK installer in a file named `src.zip`. It's often just sitting in your install directory. Unzip it, and have a look.

If it's not there, you may have chosen not to install it; reinstall the JDK and watch for the "source code" option, making sure to include it.

Answer (score 14):

I frequently use http://docjar.com for this purpose.

Example: I want to see the source code for `String`. Search for the FQCN, `java.lang.string` (using the "Package/class Name" option). Click the result you want, then click the `source` link at the top of the page. Voila: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html

Comment: [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/) is another great online ressource for quick source code inspection, but as they print linenumbers, copy&paste of code from there into java source files is ... annoying ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D - just click the little "Raw" link on the top right of the screen.

Comment: @Andreas_D GrepCode is not working nowadays... Any idea? Have they redirected or something?

Answer (score 4):

`src.zip` usually comes with JDK.

Answer (score 3):

I also find http://www.codeatlas.com to be a great place to look for JVM based source code in general. For example, if you are ever looking for how java.awt.ActionEvent is implemented you can find it here:

http://www.codatlas.com/project/L_fXVCOhW4_lzXEd3R5DNQ__/master/src/share/classes/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.java?keyword=ActionEvent&line=59

What's nice about it is that it gives an IDE like browsing experience by adding cross-reference and syntax highlighting.

Comment: Links are broken.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use linux distributions, like ubuntu, archlinux, etc. You can always get **openjdk source code** via corresponding package management system. This means you can choose a faster mirror to get the source code.

For ubuntu users:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-source
```

For Archlinux users:

```
$ sudo pacman -S openjdk7-src
```

The source will be located in the `$JAVA_HOME`, somewhere like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/src.zip`.

Other distributions will have likewise package names, so not listed here.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use Eclipse to attach the source code in C:\users\program files\jdkx.x
2) Use [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/) if you are just browsing the code and to save memory used by heavy weight eclipse on your machine