# How does a Set determine the order of its values?

Tags: java, set

I wrote a simple program that takes an array of strings that get converted into a list, then into a Set, which is finally printed.
 Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"hello", "goodbye", "welcome", "thanks"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    System.out.println(list);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

The set returns
    [hello, goodbye, welcome, thanks] 
    [hello, thanks, goodbye, welcome]

And no matter what order I make the array it returns the Set in that particular order. So how does Set<> determine in what order the values should be put into?

Comment: actually you can just inspect the java source code internals. Just remember to check how the data is entered and how the data is read in the toString() method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288377/view-java-source-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the elements in a Set is determined by the order of the elements in its `Iterator` and, as specified in [Set.iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29)

> The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

So there is no inherent order to a `Set`.

However, `Set` is only an `interface`. There are various implementstions of a `Set` that **do** provide a guarantee.

- There's a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) - which doesn't - i.e. it optimises itself to achieve `O(1)` at the expense of a predictable order.
- There's a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) - which maintains the natural order of the objects - i.e. "ab" < "ac" and 1 < 10 or any order you define using a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).
- There's an [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) - which orders by the `enum` ordinal order - kind of like `TreeSet`.
- There's a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) - which orders in the order the items were added.
- There are other more obscure implementations of [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) that also have their own character.

The `ConcurrentSkipListSet` & `TreeSet` classes are represented by the [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html) and [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) interfaces.

In Java 21+, with [sequenced collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431), the [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) interface covers three classes: `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, `LinkedHashSet`, `TreeSet`.

Comment: If there is no inherent order, why is this so, how can something be so arbitrary yet even creating a random class is only pseudorandom and uses system time. So how can it have no order?

Comment: @PsyCode - There is always an order - the critical point is that the order is only **defined** for specific implementations of the set, inall other cases you cannot assume a specific order. It is all a tradeoff - by allowing a `HashSet` to iterate in any order it likes it can achieve `O(1)` inserts.

Comment: Wow thanks, extremely descriptive AND it directly answers and explain my question! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The iteration order of a `HashSet` is an implementation detail that may change from release to release.  You should assume that the ordering is magic, inscrutable, and subject to change.

(In practice, it's affected by the hash codes of the elements, the smearing function HashSet uses internally, and the order the hash buckets appear generally.)